# Special case for biased coin flip with consecutive heads and n tries

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have a biased coin flip. Suppose the coin is flipped n times and k is the number of consecutive heads. p is the probability of heads and 1-p for tails. The required is to find the number of consecutive heads, so that for n=4 and k=1 the case of HTTH is considered, but HHTT is not considered as two heads appear in a row.
For example if we assumed that the probability of getting heads p=0.5 then the answer for the probability of having single head in consecutive is 7/16 for n=4 as can be seen below
THTH, HTHT, HTTH, TTTH, TTHT, THTT, HTTT

Is there a general rule that satisfies this assumption?

Comment: I guess no could refer me to a clue